# getting error of undefined variable while trying to write data into excel from gui in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import IntVar
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import random
import time;
import datetime
import tcl
import tkinter.colorchooser
import xlsxwriter as xs
#wb=xs.Workbook('Restaurant.xlsx')
#ws=wb.add_worksheet('Mysheet')
#ws.write('B2', 'Data')
#Marks = [var1,var2, var3, var4, var5, var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16]
#Names=[E_RJthali, E_MHthali,E_PBthali,E_KingsSpc,
#       E_Tea,E_Coffee, E_Coke,E_PaneerSpc,E_PizzaMeal,E_ChineseMeal,
#       E_SI_platter,E_DesertCombo,E_BurgerCombo,E_BangaliSweet,E_GJthali,
#    E_Saladmix ]
#ws.write_column('B5', Marks)
#ws.write_column('A5',Names)
##chart = wb.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
##chart.add_series({'values':'=Mysheet!$B$5:$B$10'})
#ws.insert_chart('D15',chart)
#wb.close()
#


import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np


root= tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
root.title("Kings Kitchen")
root.configure(background='Orange')

Tops = Frame(root, width=1350,height=100,bd=14, relief="raise")
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1 = Frame(root, width=950,height=650,bd=8, relief="raise")
f1.pack(side=LEFT)
f2 = Frame(root, width=440,height=650,bd=8, relief="raise")
f2.pack(side=RIGHT)

ft2 = Frame(f2, width=440,height=450,bd=12, relief="raise")
ft2.pack(side=TOP)
fb2 = Frame(f2, width=440,height=250,bd=16, relief="raise")
fb2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

f1a = Frame(f1, width=900,height=330,bd=8, relief="raise")
f1a.pack(side=TOP)
f2a = Frame(f1, width=900,height=320,bd=6, relief="raise")
f2a.pack(side=BOTTOM)

f1aa = Frame(f1a, width = 700, height=330,bd=16, relief="raise")
f1aa.pack(side=LEFT)
f1ab = Frame(f1a, width = 600, height=330,bd=16, relief="raise")
f1ab.pack(side=RIGHT)


f2aa = Frame(f2a, width = 450, height=330,bd=14, relief="raise")
f2aa.pack(side=LEFT)
f2ab = Frame(f2a, width = 450, height=330,bd=14, relief="raise")
f2ab.pack(side=RIGHT)

Tops.configure(background='yellow')
f1.configure(background='yellow')
f2.configure(background='yellow')

##==================================================================HEADING==========================================================================

lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=('arial',60,'bold'), text= " KINGS KITCHEN ", bd=10)
lblInfo.grid(row=0,column=0)
lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=('arial',20,'italic'),text=" Developed By Onkar Tekade (45,SEM-IV)",bd=10)
lblInfo.grid(row=1,column=0)

#===================================================================COST OF ITEMS=============================================================

def CostofItems():
    Item1=float(E_RJthali.get())
    Item2=float(E_MHthali.get())
    Item3=float(E_PBthali.get())
    Item4=float(E_KingsSpc.get())
    Item5=float(E_Tea.get())
    Item6=float(E_Coffee.get()) 
    Item7=float(E_Coke.get())
    Item8=float(E_PaneerSpc.get())

    Item9=float(E_PizzaMeal.get()) 
    Item10=float(E_ChineseMeal.get())
    Item11=float(E_SI_platter.get())
    Item12=float(E_DesertCombo.get())
    Item13=float(E_BurgerCombo.get())
    Item14=float(E_BangaliSweet.get())
    Item15=float(E_GJthali.get())
    Item16=float(E_Saladmix.get())

    PriceofDrinks = (Item1 * 120) + (Item2 * 250) + (Item3 * 240) + (Item4 * 150) + (Item5 * 200) + (Item6 * 300) + (Item7 * 220) + (Item8 * 100)

    PriceofCakes = (Item9 * 120) + (Item10 * 150) + (Item11 * 240) + (Item12 * 220) + (Item13 * 250) + (Item14 * 300) + (Item15 * 200) + (Item16 * 250)

    DrinksPrice ="Rs", str ('%.2f'%(PriceofDrinks))

    CakesPrice ="Rs", str ('%.2f'%(PriceofCakes))

    CostofCakes.set(CakesPrice)

    CostofDrinks.set(DrinksPrice)

    SC= "Rs" , str('%.2f'%(1.59))
    ServiceCharge.set(SC)

    SubTotalofITEMS = "Rs" , str('%.2f'%(PriceofDrinks + PriceofCakes + 1.59))
    SubTotal.set(SubTotalofITEMS)

    Tax= "Rs" , str('%.2f'%((PriceofDrinks + PriceofCakes + 1.59)* 0.15))
    PaidTax.set(Tax)

    TT = ((PriceofDrinks + PriceofCakes + 1.59)*0.15)
    TC = "Rs" , str('%.2f'%(PriceofDrinks + PriceofCakes + 1.59 + TT))
    TotalCost.set(TC)
#
##=======================================================METHODS=======================================================================
def qExit():
   root.destroy()

def Reset():
    PaidTax.set("")
    SubTotal.set("")
    TotalCost.set("")
    CostofDrinks.set("")
    CostofCakes.set("")
    ServiceCharge.set("")
    txtReceipt.delete("1.0",END)

    E_RJthali.set("0")
    E_MHthali.set("0")
    E_PBthali.set("0")
    E_KingsSpc.set("0")
    E_Tea.set("0")
    E_Coffee.set("0")
    E_Coke.set("0")
    E_PaneerSpc.set("0")

    E_PizzaMeal.set("0")
    E_ChineseMeal.set("0")
    E_SI_platter.set("0")
    E_DesertCombo.set("0")
    E_BurgerCombo.set("0")
    E_BangaliSweet.set("0")
    E_GJthali.set("0")
    E_Saladmix.set("0")
#
#             
    var1.set(0)    
    var2.set(0)
    var3.set(0)
    var4.set(0)
    var5.set(0)
    var6.set(0)
    var7.set(0)
    var8.set(0)
    var9.set(0)
    var10.set(0)
    var11.set(0)
    var12.set(0)
    var13.set(0)
    var14.set(0)
    var15.set(0)
    var16.set(0)
#
    txtRJthali.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtMHthali.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtPBthali.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtKingsSpc.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtTea.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtCoffee.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtCoke.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtPaneerSpc.configure(state=DISABLED)

    txtPizzaMeal.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtChineseMeal.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtSI_platter.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtDesertCombo.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtBurgerCombo.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtBangaliSweet.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtGJthali.configure(state=DISABLED)
    txtSaladmix.configure(state=DISABLED)
##======================================================================RECEIPT============================================================================

def Receipt():
    txtReceipt.delete("1.0",END)
    x = random.randint(10908, 500876)
    y= random.randint(1,10)
    randomRef = str(x)
    randomRef = str(y)
    Receipt_Ref.set("BILL"+ randomRef)
    Receipt_Ref.set("TAB"+randomRef)
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'Receipt Ref:\t\t\t'+Receipt_Ref.get() + '\t\t'+ DateofOrder.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'Items\t\t\t'+"Count of Items \n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'RJthali:\t\t\t'+ E_RJthali.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'MHthali:\t\t\t'+ E_MHthali.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'PBthali:\t\t\t'+ E_PBthali.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'KingsSpc:\t\t\t'+ E_KingsSpc.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'Tea:\t\t\t'+ E_Tea.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'Coffee:\t\t\t'+ E_Coffee.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'Coke:\t\t\t'+ E_Coke.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'PaneerSpc:\t\t\t'+ E_PaneerSpc.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'PizzaMeal:\t\t\t'+ E_PizzaMeal.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'ChineseMeal:\t\t\t'+ E_ChineseMeal.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'SI_platter:\t\t\t'+ E_SI_platter.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'DesertCombo:\t\t\t'+E_DesertCombo.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'BurgerCombo:\t\t\t'+ E_BurgerCombo.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'BangaliSweet:\t\t\t'+ E_BangaliSweet.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'GJthali:\t\t\t'+ E_GJthali.get()+"\n")
    #txtReceipt.insert(END,'Saladmix:\t\t\t'+ E_Saladmix.get()+"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'C.I:\t'+ CostofDrinks.get()+ '\tTax:\t' + PaidTax.get() +"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'C.I:\t'+ CostofCakes.get()+ '\tS.T:\t' +SubTotal.get() +"\n")
    txtReceipt.insert(END,'S.C:\t'+ ServiceCharge.get()+ '\tTot:\t' + TotalCost.get() +"\n")


##=========================================================================CHECKBOX==========================================================================
#
def chkbutton_value():
    if (var1.get() == 1):
        txtRJthali.configure(state= NORMAL)
    elif var1.get()== 0:
            txtRJthali.configure(state= DISABLED)
            E_RJthali.set("0")
    if (var2.get() == 1):
        txtMHthali.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var2.get()== 0:
            txtMHthali.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_MHthali.set("0")
    if (var3.get() == 1):
        txtPBthali.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var3.get()== 0:
            txtPBthali.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_PBthali.set("0")
    if (var4.get() == 1):
        txtKingsSpc.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var4.get()== 0:
            txtKingsSpc.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_KingsSpc.set("0")
    if (var5.get() == 1):
        txtTea.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var5.get()== 0:
            txtTea.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_Tea.set("0")
    if (var6.get() == 1):
        txtCoffee.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var6.get()== 0:
            txtCoffee.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_Coffee.set("0")
    if (var7.get() == 1):
        txtCoke.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var7.get()== 0:
            txtCoke.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_Coke.set("0")
    if (var8.get() == 1):
        txtPaneerSpc.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var8.get()==0:
            txtPaneerSpc.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_PaneerSpc.set("0")
    if (var9.get() == 1):
        txtPizzaMeal.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var9.get()== 0:
            txtPizzaMeal.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_PizzaMeal.set("0")
    if (var10.get() == 1):
        txtChineseMeal.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var10.get()== 0:
            txtChineseMeal.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_ChineseMeal.set("0")
    if (var11.get() == 1):
        txtSI_platter.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var11.get()== 0:
            txtSI_platter.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_SI_platter.set("0")
    if (var12.get() == 1):
        txtDesertCombo.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var12.get()== 0:
            txtDesertCombo.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_DesertCombo.set("0")
    if (var13.get() == 1):
        txtBurgerCombo.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var13.get()== 0:
            txtBurgerCombo.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_BurgerCombo.set("0")
    if (var14.get() == 1):
        txtBangaliSweet.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var14.get()== 0:
            txtBangaliSweet.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_BangaliSweet.set("0")
    if (var15.get() == 1):
        txtGJthali.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var15.get()== 0:
            txtGJthali.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_GJthali.set("0")
    if (var16.get() == 1):
        txtSaladmix.configure(state=NORMAL)
    elif var16.get()== 0:
            txtSaladmix.configure(state=DISABLED)
            E_Saladmix.set("0")
#  
#   
##==========================================================VARIABLES===============================================================================
var1= IntVar()
var2= IntVar()
var3= IntVar()
var4= IntVar()
var5= IntVar()
var6= IntVar()
var7= IntVar()
var8= IntVar()
var9= IntVar()
var10= IntVar()
var11= IntVar()
var12= IntVar()
var13= IntVar()
var14= IntVar()
var15= IntVar()
var16= IntVar()


#var1= StringVar()
#var2= StringVar()
#var3= StringVar()
#var4= StringVar()
#var5= StringVar()
#var6= StringVar()
#var7= StringVar()
#var8= StringVar()
#var9= StringVar()
#var10= StringVar()
#var11= StringVar()
#var12= StringVar()
#var13= StringVar()
#var14= StringVar()
#var15= StringVar()
#var16= StringVar()

DateofOrder=StringVar()
Receipt_Ref=StringVar()
PaidTax=StringVar()
SubTotal=StringVar()
TotalCost=StringVar()
CostofCakes=StringVar()
CostofDrinks=StringVar()
ServiceCharge=StringVar()


E_RJthali=StringVar()
E_MHthali=StringVar()
E_PBthali=StringVar()
E_KingsSpc=StringVar()
E_Tea=StringVar()
E_Coffee=StringVar()
E_Coke=StringVar()
E_PaneerSpc=StringVar()
E_PizzaMeal=StringVar()
E_ChineseMeal=StringVar()
E_SI_platter=StringVar()
E_DesertCombo=StringVar()
E_BurgerCombo=StringVar()
E_BangaliSweet=StringVar()
E_GJthali=StringVar()
E_Saladmix=StringVar()

E_RJthali.set("0")
E_MHthali.set("0")
E_PBthali.set("0")
E_KingsSpc.set("0")
E_Tea.set("0")
E_Coffee.set("0")
E_Coke.set("0")
E_PaneerSpc.set("0")

E_PizzaMeal.set("0")
E_ChineseMeal.set("0")
E_SI_platter.set("0")
E_DesertCombo.set("0")
E_BurgerCombo.set("0")
E_BangaliSweet.set("0")
E_GJthali.set("0")
#E_Saladmix.set("0")
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[var1,var2, var3, var4, var5, var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13,var14,var15,var16],
                   'b':[E_RJthali, E_MHthali,E_PBthali,E_KingsSpc,
       E_Tea,E_Coffee, E_Coke,E_PaneerSpc,E_PizzaMeal,E_ChineseMeal,
       E_SI_platter,E_DesertCombo,E_BurgerCombo,E_BangaliSweet,E_GJthali,
   E_Saladmix ]})

writer = ExcelWriter('Pandas-Example2.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

> here  getting  error of Unsupported type  in write()
>   in above statement df=...
>
> ### its restaurant management system project in python rest code is working properly but i want to store order details in exccel

```
DateofOrder.set(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
#
##=================================================DRINKS===================================================================================================================
#
lblTable_no=Label(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),text="Tab",bd=8)
lblTable_no.grid(row=0,column=0)
RJthali = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  RJ_THALI        ", variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=1,sticky=W)

MHthali = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  MH_THALI        ", variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=2,sticky=W)

PBthali = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  PB_THALI        ", variable=var3, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=3,sticky=W)

KingsSpc = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  KINGs_SPC      ", variable=var4, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=4,sticky=W)

Tea = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  TEA         ", variable=var5, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=5,sticky=W)

Coffee = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  COFFEE       ", variable=var6, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=6,sticky=W)

Coke = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  COKE       ", variable=var7, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=7,sticky=W)

PaneerSpc = Checkbutton(f1aa, text="  PANEER_SPC        ", variable=var8, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=8,sticky=W)

#====================================================CAKES======================================================================================================================

PizzaMeal = Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" Coffee_cake        ", variable=var9, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=0,sticky=W)

ChineseMeal = Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" CHINESE_MEAL         ", variable=var10, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=1,sticky=W)

SI_platter= Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" SI_PLATTER         ", variable=var11, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=2,sticky=W)

DesertCombo = Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" DESERT_COMBO         ", variable=var12, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=3,sticky=W)

BurgerCombo= Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" BURGER-COMBO      ", variable=var13, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=4,sticky=W)

BangaliSweet= Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" BANGALI_SWEET        ", variable=var14, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=5,sticky=W)

GJthali = Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" GJ_THALI         ", variable=var15, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=6,sticky=W)

#Saladmix = Checkbutton(f1ab, text=" SALAD_MIX      ", variable=var16, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, font=('arial',16,'bold'),command=chkbutton_value).grid(row=9,sticky=W)


#=====================================================ENTER WIDGE DRINKS================================================================================================================

txtRJthali = Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_RJthali, state=DISABLED)
txtRJthali.grid(row=0,column=1)

txtMHthali = Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_MHthali, state=DISABLED)
txtMHthali.grid(row=1,column=1)

txtPBthali = Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_PBthali,state=DISABLED)
txtPBthali.grid(row=2,column=1)

txtKingsSpc= Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_KingsSpc,state=DISABLED)
txtKingsSpc.grid(row=3,column=1)

txtTea = Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_Tea,state=DISABLED)
txtTea.grid(row=4,column=1)

txtCoffee = Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_Coffee,state=DISABLED)
txtCoffee.grid(row=5,column=1)

txtCoke = Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_Coke,state=DISABLED)
txtCoke.grid(row=6,column=1)

txtPaneerSpc = Entry(f1aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_PaneerSpc,state=DISABLED)
txtPaneerSpc.grid(row=7,column=1)



#=====================================================ENTER WIDGE CAKES========================================================================================

txtPizzaMeal = Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_PizzaMeal,state=DISABLED)
txtPizzaMeal.grid(row=0,column=1)
txtChineseMeal = Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_ChineseMeal,state=DISABLED)
txtChineseMeal.grid(row=1,column=1)
txtSI_platter = Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_SI_platter,state=DISABLED)
txtSI_platter.grid(row=2,column=1)
txtDesertCombo = Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_DesertCombo,state=DISABLED)
txtDesertCombo.grid(row=3,column=1)

txtBurgerCombo = Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_BurgerCombo,state=DISABLED)
txtBurgerCombo.grid(row=4,column=1)

txtBangaliSweet= Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_BangaliSweet,state=DISABLED)
txtBangaliSweet.grid(row=5,column=1)

txtGJthali = Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_GJthali,state=DISABLED)
txtGJthali.grid(row=6,column=1)

txtSaladmix = Entry(f1ab,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=6,width=6,justify='left',textvariable=E_Saladmix,state=DISABLED)
txtSaladmix.grid(row=7,column=1)



#===========================================================INFORMATION==========================================================================================

lblReceipt = Label(ft2,font=('arial',10,'bold'),text="Get Receipt:",bd=2,anchor='w')
lblReceipt.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
txtReceipt = Text(ft2,font=('arial',6,'bold'),bd=6,width=60,height=30,bg="white")
txtReceipt.grid(row=1,column=0)


#=========================================================ITEM COST INFORMATION=============================================================================

lblCostofItems=Label(f2aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),text="Cost1",bd=8)
lblCostofItems.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
txtCostofItems=Entry(f2aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=8,insertwidth=2,justify='left',textvariable=CostofDrinks)
txtCostofItems.grid(row=2,column=1)

lblCostofItems=Label(f2aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),text="Cost2",bd=8)
lblCostofItems.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
txtCostofItems=Entry(f2aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=8,insertwidth=2,justify='left',textvariable=CostofCakes)
txtCostofItems.grid(row=3,column=1)

lblServiceCharge=Label(f2aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),text="Service Charge",bd=8)
lblServiceCharge.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
txtServiceCharge=Entry(f2aa,font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=8,insertwidth=2,justify='left',textvariable=ServiceCharge)
txtServiceCharge.grid(row=4,column=1)


#=========================================================PAYMENT INFORMATION===============================================================================

lblPaidTax=Label(f2ab,font=('arial',10,'bold'),text="Tax paid",bd=6)
lblPaidTax.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
txtPaidTax=Entry(f2ab,font=('arial',10,'bold'),bd=8,insertwidth=2,justify='left',textvariable=PaidTax)
txtPaidTax.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)

lblSubTotal=Label(f2ab,font=('arial',10,'bold'),text="Sub Total",bd=6)
lblSubTotal.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
txtSubTotal=Entry(f2ab,font=('arial',10,'bold'),bd=8,insertwidth=2,justify='left',textvariable=SubTotal)
txtSubTotal.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W)

lblTotalCost=Label(f2ab,font=('arial',10,'bold'),text="Total Cost",bd=6)
lblTotalCost.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
txtTotalCost=Entry(f2ab,font=('arial',10,'bold'),bd=8,insertwidth=2,justify='left',textvariable=TotalCost)
txtTotalCost.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W)

#============================================================BUTTONS=============================================================================================

btnTotal=Button(fb2,padx=12,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial',7,'bold'),width=2,text="Total",command=CostofItems).grid(row=0,column=0)

btnReceipt=Button(fb2,padx=12,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial',7,'bold'),width=2,text="Receipt",command=Receipt).grid(row=0,column=1)
```

btnReset=Button(fb2,padx=12,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial',7,'bold'),width=2,text="Reset",command=Reset).grid(row=0,column=2)

btnExit=Button(fb2,padx=12,pady=1,bd=4,fg="black",font=('arial',7,'bold'),width=2,text="Exit",command=qExit).grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()

Answer (score 0):

Note: my account is new, so I can't leave comments yet. If I could, I would've suggested you write a question that describes the circumstances surrounding this problem, not just a couple of blocks of code, before I gave a possible answer. Please consider editing you question.

This code appears to written in a procedural style, rather than Object Oriented. This means the code is being interpreted top-to-bottom. Therefore, the `Data` arg being passed into `ws.write()` does not exist as far as Python is concerned. Absent of any further info about your situation, my suggestion would be to create a variable for that arg earlier in the script than `ws.write()` and use Tkinter to set the value.

```
Data=foo
wb=xs.Workbook('Restaurant.xlsx')
ws=wb.add_worksheet('Mysheet')
ws.write('B2', 'Data')
```